# Can't get one click on the mouse using jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I attempt to click on any one selection on of the buttons, sometimes I get one click (as expected) and sometimes I get more than one click fired (not what I want) using the code below given by someone on Stackoverflow...

```
var $document = $(document);
var clickCount = 0;

var treeLogic = function (event) {
    // unbind the element from the event handler
    $document.off("click", "#file", treeLogic);

    clickCount = clickCount + 1; 
    // for testing the number of clicks on each click of a button. 
    // sometimes it shows one click and sometimes it shows more than one click
    // (not what I want).

    // bind the element back to the event handler
    $document.on("click", "#file", treeLogic);
};

$document.on("click", "#file", treeLogic);
```

HTML code

```
<input type='button' id='button'></input>
```

Could be my mouse is bad? Or the logic above is bad, and if so, can someone show me how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your HTML. And an example on jsFiddle.net is usually helpful.

Comment: #file is not #button.

Comment: You don't seem to know what you are doing at first place. #file is not #button. Also, you set to unset then set again your actions.

Comment: whats the point of unbinding and rebinding on every click?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/KKvdA/

Answer (score 0):

I removed some parts .on and .off bindings .. and this works

[Jsfiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Cnnn/) :

html

```
<input type='button' id='file'></input>
```

javascript

```
var $document = $(document);
var clickCount = 0;
var treeLogic = function (event) {
    clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    console.log(clickCount);
};
$document.on("click", "#file", treeLogic);
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified version. But it also seems to work with the OP's original code: http://jsfiddle.net/KKvdA/. Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I havent tried any further, it feels like i have to read OP's minds. I thought it'd become useless to help, this question seems in a way to be deleted somehow.